# $q$-Kostant partition function and flow polytopes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, convex-polytopes, root-systems

The Kostant partition function is known to be related to volumes and Ehrhart polynomials of flow polytopes of graphs (see e.g. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00031-008-9019-8 or https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/2015/3/830/649778).

There is a natural $q$-analog of the Kostant partition function; for instance Lusztig's $q$-analog of weight multiplicity can be defined in terms of this $q$-Kostant partition function (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1453). (Note that in Type A Lusztig's $q$-analogs of weight multiplicity are also called the Kostka-Foulkes polynomials.)

Is there any work on understanding the $q$-analog of the Kostant partition function in terms of ``$q$-Ehrhart theory'' of flow polytopes?